# Draw a Corridor around a road

Tags: google-earth-pro

I want draw a corridor indicating a right-of-way around a road.
The right-of-way is 300 ft. i.e. 150 on either side of the centerline of the road.
Here I show just lines that I have hand drawn, very poorly.
How can this best be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Google Earth Pro? I'm not aware of any way to do this other than how you already started.

In QGIS, it would be trivial , using the buffer tool, [as documented here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html).

Comment: I hadn't heard of QGIS. Downloading it now. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest going through a few tutorials to learn the basics, but making buffers should be part of it (it's a one-step, automatic, tool).

Answer (score -1):

Qgis makes this easy, has advanced gis features and also has many integrations and add ons from 3rd party software